# using sklearn macro f1-score as a metric in tensorflow.keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have defined custom metric for tensorflow.keras to compute macro-f1-score after every epoch as follows:

```
from tensorflow import argmax as tf_argmax
from sklearn.metric import f1_score

def macro_f1(y_true, y_pred):
    # labels are one-hot encoded. so, need to convert
    # [1,0,0] to 0 and
    # [0,1,0] to 1 and
    # [0,0,1] to 2. Then pass these arrays to sklearn f1_score.
    y_true = tf_argmax(y_true, axis=1)
    y_pred = tf_argmax(y_pred, axis=1)
    return f1_score(y_true, y_pred, average='macro')
```

and using it during model compilation

```
model_4.compile(loss = 'categorical_crossentropy',
                optimizer = Adam(lr=init_lr, decay=init_lr / num_epochs),
                metrics = [Recall(name='recall') #, weighted_f1
                           macro_f1])
```

and when i try to fit like this:

```
history_model_4 = model_4.fit(train_image_generator.flow(x=train_imgs, y=train_targets, batch_size=batch_size),
                            validation_data = (val_imgs, val_targets),
                            epochs=num_epochs,
                            class_weight=mask_weights_train,
                            callbacks=[model_save_cb, early_stop_cb, epoch_times_cb],
                            verbose=2)
```

this is the error:

```
OperatorNotAllowedInGraphError: in user code:

    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:806 train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    <ipython-input-57-a890ea61878e>:6 macro_f1  *
        return f1_score(y_true, y_pred, average='macro')
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sklearn/metrics/_classification.py:1095 f1_score  *
        return fbeta_score(y_true, y_pred, 1, labels=labels,
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sklearn/metrics/_classification.py:1217 fbeta_score  *
        _, _, f, _ = precision_recall_fscore_support(y_true, y_pred,
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sklearn/metrics/_classification.py:1478 precision_recall_fscore_support  *
        labels = _check_set_wise_labels(y_true, y_pred, average, labels,
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sklearn/metrics/_classification.py:1301 _check_set_wise_labels  *
        y_type, y_true, y_pred = _check_targets(y_true, y_pred)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sklearn/metrics/_classification.py:80 _check_targets  *
        check_consistent_length(y_true, y_pred)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py:209 check_consistent_length  *
        uniques = np.unique(lengths)
    <__array_function__ internals>:6 unique  **
        
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numpy/lib/arraysetops.py:263 unique
        ret = _unique1d(ar, return_index, return_inverse, return_counts)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numpy/lib/arraysetops.py:311 _unique1d
        ar.sort()
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py:877 __bool__
        self._disallow_bool_casting()
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py:487 _disallow_bool_casting
        "using a `tf.Tensor` as a Python `bool`")
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py:474 _disallow_when_autograph_enabled
        " indicate you are trying to use an unsupported feature.".format(task))

    OperatorNotAllowedInGraphError: using a `tf.Tensor` as a Python `bool` is not allowed: AutoGraph did convert this function. This might indicate you are trying to use an unsupported feature.
```

What caused such errors and how do I fix it and use it as one of my evaluation metrics at the end of ever y epoch?

EDIT 1:
note: all of this has been done in a jupyter notebook, i have added ">>>"s to seperate lines

```
# getting a batch to pass to model
>>> a_batch = train_image_generator.flow(x=train_imgs, y=train_targets, batch_size=batch_size).next()
# checking its' type to ensure that it's what i though it is
>>> type(a_batch)
# passing the batch to the model
>>> logits = model_4(a_batch)
# checking the type of output
>>> type(logits)
tensorflow.python.framework.ops.EagerTensor
# extracting only the passed targets to calculate f1-score
>>> _, dummy_targets = a_batch
# checking it's type
>>> type(dummy_targets)
numpy.ndarray
>>> macro_f1(y_true=dummy_targets, y_pred=logits)
0.0811965811965812
```

Comment: Can't replicate, might be related to your data. After compiling your model try debugging with `logits = model(sample_X_batch)` ; `f1 = macro_f1(sample_y_batch, logits)` . You can add prints after your `y_true` and `y_pred` in `macro_f1`

Comment: @user2827262 check my edit now.

Comment: the function works as expected and results a score as float. It worked, i couldn't figure out what had caused the error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`sklearn` is not TensorFlow code - it is always recommended to avoid using arbitrary Python code in TF that gets executed inside TF's execution graph.

[TensorFlow addons](https://www.tensorflow.org/addons) already has an implementation of the F1 score ([tfa.metrics.F1Score](https://www.tensorflow.org/addons/api_docs/python/tfa/metrics/F1Score)), so change your code to use that instead of your custom metric

Make sure you `pip install tensorflow-addons` first and then

```py
import tensorflow_addons as tfa

model_4.compile(loss = 'categorical_crossentropy',
                optimizer = Adam(lr=init_lr, decay=init_lr / num_epochs),
                metrics = [Recall(name='recall') #, weighted_f1
                           tfa.metrics.F1Score(average='macro')])
```